# Textview layout center vertical and horizontal in ScrollView by programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

Application has `scrollview` in XML layout.

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       >
</ScrollView>
```

I want to one `textView` into this `scrollView` center.

I tried This code, set horizontal center, but vertical top.. I want both centered.

```
LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            l1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            l1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            TextView errorView = new TextView(getActivity());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            errorView.setText("TextView");
            errorView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            errorView.setLayoutParams(params);
            errorView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            l1.addView(errorView);
            scrollViewCon.addView(l1, lparams);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is getActivity here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your xml as shown below - 
Add **fillViewport** as true.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
   >
```

Removed the relative layout addition part as it is not required.

Comment: great tips! thaks anukool!